# Making asynchronous ajax call in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have a bunch of ajax calls in my angular app.

```
$scope.playerData = function(param) {           
        showLoader();
        $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:"slim.php/playerData",
            data: {'playerId': param},
        }).then(function(response) {
            ajaxCallDone();                 
        },function(response){
            handleError();
        });
    }
```

Most of my other ajax calls using Angular have same syntax. I notice that my calls are all made synchronously. If I have 5 calls to the server, each executes ONLY after the other has returned. This is not what I need. How can I make these calls synchronously. I read about $q and promises, but I am unable to understand them. I following but it did not help:

```
playerApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.useApplyAsync(true);
});
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Angular calls are asynchronous. You can see the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/httpBackend.js) of the `http backend factory` where the `async` boolean is hard-coded to `true` (line 77 at this moment). Your problem maybe comes from your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Requests are asynchronous, but i think there is another problem. Remember, that modern browsers can execute only few ajax requests simultaneously (you can have 2. Its part of [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.4)). So if you have many ajax calls browser can queue them.